# SICK lms problem/ A scan was probably missed

Tags: ros, scan, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm having a problem for which I would appreciate any kind of help :)

I'm using ubuntu 10.04, installed ros - by following tutorial, and now i have to use sicklms200, so i installed sicktoolbox - also followed tutorial.
When i try to connect to laser, problem which appears is a repeating message - "a scan was probably missed". So i looked for an answer, and got to this recommendation:

*Fire up your favorite editor and open this file (your_ros_installation_directory)/ros/diamondback/stacks/sicktoolbox/build/sicktoolbox-1.0/c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMS.cc . Go to line 2319.

In this line, add the O_NDELAY flag as shown here:...(source: http://thebattlegoeson.blogspot.com/2011/06/xyz.html)*

Problem is that I can't find this file *SickLMS.cc*, it simply dosen't exist in any of folders :/

I tried reinstalling sicktoolbox and sicktoolbox_wrapper using rosmake (like this:*$ rosdep install sicktoolbox_wrapper rviz
$ rosmake sicktoolbox_wrapper rviz*)

i also find this answer: *You'll need to install the laser_drivers stack from source in order to get all of the source files.*
I'm a total beginner with ros and ubuntu, and probably asking a stupid question, but what does this actually mean? Do i need to add some line in terminal when installing or...??

Again, I'm probably asking stupid questions, but really don't know what else to do or where to find answers so thank you in advance for any help..

edit: I've downloaded and installed the version of ros for ubuntu lucid 10.04 and it's ros fuerte (followed the tutorial *http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu*, and installed full version as recommended )

thank you all for answers, I will check out if it works as soon as the SICK is available:)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42981/sick-lms-problem/-a-scan-was-probably-missed/) by [em](https://answers.ros.org/users/3138/em/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-04**:
It's a fine question. But, please edit it so we know what version of ROS you installed and exactly which tutorials you are following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on which ROS version you installed, you may find [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) helpful. It explains how to check out ROS source files, which you can edit, build and run.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like @joq said, we definitely need to know what version of ROS you are using and which answers you are following (mainly so we we can update those questions with newer answers).

I believe this problem was fixed in the Fuerte release of laser_drivers. See the changelist with link to tickets here: http://ros.org/wiki/laser_drivers/ChangeList/1.6

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [em](https://answers.ros.org/users/3138/em/) on 2012-09-05**:
It started working, actually I got that message "Data stream started", so thank you :) (I installed it all again, and it just worked.. )